# experience at/in/on high school levels

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Are the prepositions *at, in, on* interchangeable here? If yes, do they all mean the same?

> I have student-teaching experience at/in/on (all) high school levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *at* is your best choice; that's the preposition usually used in that context.

More specifically, I would use *at*, because we usually say [*at all levels*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20all%20levels,on%20all%20levels&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):

> *I have student-teaching experience at the high school level.*

It may be worth noting that, at least in the U.S. educational system, all of high school is considered one *level*, consisting of four *grades*. So, this is the way I'd recommend saying this (depending on what grades you taught):

> *I have student-teaching experience at the high school level*.  [i.e., *I taught students in grades 9 - 12*]
>   *I have student-teaching experience in all high school grades*.  [i.e., *students in grades 9, 10, 11 & 12*]
>   *I have student-teaching experience at both the high school and middle school level*. [i.e., *students in grades 9 - 12, as well as students in grades 6 - 8*]

However, that might be different in other countries.

One other thing worth mentioning: when we use a past tense verb with the phrase "in high school," that usually indicates an activity we did as a student.

> *I took geometry in high school.*

So, I would avoid, "I had my student-teaching experience in Chattanooga High School" (even though it's not grammatically incorrect), because that could be interpreted to mean that you did student teaching while you were a high school student. It would be much better to say:

> *I had my student-teaching experience at Chattanooga High School.*