# Is "on that level" correct?

Tags: prepositions

Here on this website, I have found a sentence containing the preposition *at* before the noun *level* and it seems correct to me: [experience at/in/on high school levels](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7912/experience-at-in-on-high-school-levels/7916#7916)

> I have student-teaching experience at the high school level.

However, I wonder now whether one could also say *on ... level* in other contexts as in

> On a certain level you should try to immerse yourself in the language you want to learn ...

So I think with *at* it would be correct but I am not so sure about the preposition *on* here although my gut feeling tells me it is wrong. But I am not a native speaker, of course. Could someone of you tell me whether it is wrong or right?

Comment: "On a certain level" is, in your example, an idiom, roughly meaning "while thinking about it in a certain way" - it's similar to "on the one hand", but without quite the same implication that a second alternative will follow.

Comment: Idiomatically, ***at** a certain level* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+certain+level%2Cat+a+certain+level&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20certain%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20certain%20level%3B%2Cc0), but it would be stretching a point to claim that ***on*** is actually "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Level* can mean two things - how something measures against a scale, and a platform one stands upon.

If by "level" you mean "how high, how much," *at* is used.  Think of a scale, like that on the side of a measuring cup, and with this use of *level* you are asking *where* the thing you are measuring lies on such a scale.  You would typically use the preposition *at* when answering *where*.

If by "level" you mean a platform one stands upon, *on* is used.

Also, @MrTheWalrus is 100% correct, *on a certain level* is an idiom and should be treated as a special case.  So is *on the/that/a same level*:

> Her and I were on that same level.

This is an informal (if not slang) idiom that means the two people here had a mutual understanding about something, likely not explicitly spoken.